# In John 15:1, when Jesus said, “I am ‘the true’ (ἡ ἀληθινή) vine,” was the word “true” a random choice or is there any significance?

Tags: john

1. If it was not, what the possible significance can be deduced?
2. Does ἄμπελος refer the vine tree or the vinyard where vine tree is planted as some commentator suggests?

Text:John 15:1 (ESV)
 “I am the true vine, and my Father is the vinedresser.

Answer (score 5):

Text: John 15:1 (ESV) “I am the true vine, and my Father is the vinedresser.

In the OT  the house  of Israel is called the "the vineyard of the Lord"

Isaiah 51:7 KJV

> 7 For the vineyard of the Lord of hosts is the house of Israel, and
>   the men of Judah his pleasant plant: and he looked for judgment, but
>   behold oppression; for righteousness, but behold a cry.

At Jeremiah 2:21 God refers to the unfaithful nation of Israel as "the degenerate plant of a strange vine".

Jeremiah 2:21  (KJV)

> 21 Yet I had planted thee a noble vine, wholly a right seed: how then
>   art thou turned into the degenerate plant of a strange vine unto me?

Unlike the degenerate unfaithful nation of Israel, Jesus is the "true vine" and his Father is the vinedresser. Jesus then likens his faithful disciples as the branches and implores them to remain in union with him, in order to be fruitful and productive.

> John 15:5 NASB  “I am the vine, you are the branches. He who abides in Me, and I in
>   him, bears much fruit; for without Me you can do nothing.

The branches of a literal vine need to remain attached to the vine in order to remain alive and thus produce fruit, likewise, the followers of Christ need to remain in union with Christ in order to produce spiritual fruitage.

Comment: I have questioned  to other two Answers and that is: in effect, you too are saying, If my understanding is correct, in the context of one Parable,  vine=Israel & vine=Jesus, if so,  seem it is inconsistent, especially, in consideration of words in V-5 -9,: "I am the vine"; abides in me...etc. Jesus is explicitly identifying Himself as the true vine. If my misunderstood you, its my bad.

Comment: Sam ; God likened literal Israel to a vine (Psalm 80:8-15 and Isaiah 5:2,7). Similarly Jesus used a metaphor: "I am the true vine, and My Father is the vinedresser." (John 15:1 NASB"

Comment: Yes, in the Scripture  Israel likend to the vine, but that does not apply to all "vine" contexts, especially this one.  Your answer ends referring vine to Christ, but also to "Israel"  by your quote of Is 51:7 & Jer 2:21, which seems to be an inconsistency.

Comment: The vine always refers to Israel, but the true Israel - "she/he who sees God" - is also the bride, which is joined with Christ and is his body, thus Christ is the true vine as well and as he is the source of life for the body, so he is the true vine that gives life to the branches.  A similar analogy holds for the New Jerusalem, e.g. the "true" Jerusalem, which comes down from Heaven prepared as a bride adorned for her husband. All these are the same metaphors.

Answer (score 4):

Trench has noteworthy remarks on ἀληθής and ἀληθινός in his *Synonyms of the New Testament.*<sup>1</sup> First, he notes that the Latin of the Vulgate often aids in distinguishing between ἀληθής and ἀληθινός by translating them by the Latin words *verax* and *verus*, respectively.

[image]

He further notes that, over time, English has failed to distinguish between the two, eventually translating both by the adjective “true.”

[image]

As the *Oxford English Dictionary* notes, on its entry for “very,” as an adjective it was “Very common from c1300 to c1600; now rare except as an echo of Biblical usage.”

[image]

Thayer notes that certain earlier English translations (e.g., Wycliffe’s) did distinguish the Greek words by translating them into English as “true” and “very,” respectively.

[image]

[image]
<sup>John 15, *Wycliffe’s New Testament*</sup>

As both Trench and C. Stroud note, it is retained and translated appropriately in the Nicene Creed.

[image]

Trench notes, also, that the adjective ἀληθινός has in it the suffix -ινος which “expresses the material out of which anything is made.”<sup>2</sup>

He then cites Karl Friedrich August Kahnis in his *Die Lehre vom Abendmahle*<sup>3</sup> whom he says well explains the difference between ἀληθής and ἀληθινός.

[image]

> ἀληθής and ἀληθινός differ thus, in that the former word (ἀληθής) excludes the untrue and unreal, [while] the latter [word] (ἀληθινός) excludes what does not correspond to its idea. The measure of ἀληθής is the reality; the measure of ἀληθινός [is] the idea. In ἀληθής, the idea corresponds to the object; in ἀληθινός, the object [corresponds] to the idea.

Trench provides a couple examples to illustrate the point. Xenophon<sup>4</sup> said of Cyrus that he commanded «στρατεύματι ἀληθινῷ», “a very army” or “an army indeed.” Trench says that Xenophon “would not have altogether refused this name of ‘army’ to inferior hosts.” Plato<sup>5</sup> referred to the sea beyond the pillars of Hercules (straits of Gibraltar) as «τὸν ἀληθινὸν ἐκεῖνον πόντον», “that very sea.”

Trench further remarked,

[image]

On the word ἀληθινός, Origen commented that something is said to be ἀληθινός in distinction to the shadow (σκιά), figure/type (τύπος), and likeness/semblance (εἰκών).<sup>6</sup>

**Very Light**

In the Old Testament, the Law of Moses was a light.<sup>7</sup> In the New Testament, John the Baptist was a light,<sup>8</sup> as well as the disciples of the Lord.<sup>9</sup> The Lord Jesus Christ is the **very light** because he illuminates every one who comes into the world,<sup>10</sup> shining in the darkness which cannot overcome him,<sup>11</sup> whereas other light only shines so bright, so far, for so long.

**Very Bread**

In the Old Testament, God gave the Israelites manna from heaven,<sup>12</sup> “bread of the nobles,”<sup>13</sup> sustaining the Israelites while they wandered in the wilderness.

The Lord Jesus Christ is **very bread** because those who eat of him shall never hunger,<sup>14</sup> and in fact, never die,<sup>15</sup> whereas those who eat other bread will hunger again.

**Very Wine**

In the Old Testament, the nation of Israel was a vine planted by God Himself.<sup>16</sup> But, because of unfruitfulness, that vine was burned with fire and cut down.<sup>17</sup> The Lord Jesus Christ is the **very vine** because he is very Israel,<sup>18</sup> and the branches of the **very vine** are those “in Christ” who are “fruitful in every good work.”<sup>19</sup>

If the very vine is Jesus Christ, then the very vine is also Christ’s body, the Church. To be precise, the members of Christ’s body are the branches of the vine. While there are fruitful branches, there are also unfruitful branches that the Father prunes from the vine.<sup>20</sup> These unfruitful branches are not unbelievers, for they would never be in the very vine to begin with. Rather, they are believers who are lukewarm,<sup>21</sup> or as Meyer calls them, *Maulchristen* (“mouth Christians”)<sup>22</sup>—those Christians who profess to be Christian but their works betray them,<sup>23</sup> for Christ said, “Every tree is known by its fruit.”<sup>24</sup> Even the apostle Paul warned Christians not to be high-minded, but fear, lest God breaks them off of the olive tree.<sup>25</sup>

---

| Footnotes |
| --- |
| <sup>1</sup> Trench, § VIII, p. [25–26](https://books.google.com/books?id=yvgsAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA25#v=onepage&q&f=false) <sup>2</sup> Using the Perseus search function, searching for words ending in “inos,” and and then searching the results for the phrase “made of,” one may observe the multitudes of adjectives used in this sense. Some examples include ξύλινος (from ξύλον), “made of wood; wooden”; γήινος (from γῆ), “made of earth; earthen”; κρίθινος (from κριθή), “made of barley”; λίθινος (from λίθος), “made of stone”; etc. <sup>3</sup> Kahnis, p. [119](https://books.google.com/books?id=eMkrAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA119#v=onepage&q&f=false) <sup>4</sup> Xenophon, *Anabasis*, 1.9.17 <sup>5</sup> Plato, *Timaeus*, 25a <sup>6</sup> Origen, p. [120](https://books.google.com/books?id=NklFyxtsJoIC&pg=PA119#v=onepage&q&f=false) <sup>7</sup> Pro. 6:23 <sup>8</sup> John 5:35 <sup>9</sup> Matt. 5:14–16 <sup>10</sup> John 1:9 <sup>11</sup> John 1:5 <sup>12</sup> Psa. 78:24; Exo. 16:25 <sup>13</sup> Psa. 78:25: לֶחֶם אַבִּירִים (*lechem abbirim*), which Origen translated as ἄρτον ἀγγέλων, Aquila and Theodotion as ἄρτον δυναστῶν, and Symmachus as ἄρτον μεγάλων (Field, Vol. 2, p. [225](https://archive.org/details/origenishexaplor02origuoft/page/225/mode/2up)). <sup>14</sup> John 6:35 <sup>15</sup> John 6:50 <sup>16</sup> Psa. 80:8 cf. Lev. 22:33 <sup>17</sup> Psa. 80:16 cf. Jer. 2:21 <sup>18</sup> Isa. 49:3; Matt. 2:15 cf. Hos. 11:1 <sup>19</sup> Col. 1:10 cf. Luke 8:15; Rom. 7:4 <sup>20</sup> John 15:2 <sup>21</sup> Rev. 3:16 <sup>22</sup> Meyer, p. [531](https://books.google.com/books?id=8SI7AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA531#v=onepage&q&f=false) <sup>23</sup> Jam. 2:17–18 <sup>24</sup> Luke 6:43–44 <sup>25</sup> Rom. 11:21. The same principle would apply to the vine. The unfruitful branches are removed/broken off. |

| References |
| --- |
| Field, Frederick. [*Origenis Hexaplorum.*](https://archive.org/details/origenishexaplor02origuoft) Vol. 2. Oxonii: E Typographeo Clarendoniano, 1875. Kahnis, Karl Friedrich August. [*Die Lehre vom Abendmahle.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=eMkrAAAAYAAJ) Leipzig: Dörffling & Franke, 1851. Meyer, Heinrich August Wilhelm. [*Kritisch exegetischer Kommentar über das Neue Testament, Zweite Abtheilung, Kritisch exegetisches Handbuch über das Evangelium des Johannes.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=8SI7AAAAcAAJ) 5th ed. Vol. 2. Göttingen: Vandenboeck and Ruprecht, 1869. Origen. [*Patrologiæ Cursus Completus: Series Græca Prior.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=NklFyxtsJoIC) “ΤΩΝ ΕΙΣ ΤΟ ΚΑΤΑ ΙΩΑΝΝΗΝ ΕΥΑΓΓΕΛΙΟΝ ΕΞΗΓΗΤΙΚΩΝ, ΤΟΜΟΣ Β'” (“The Explanations on the Gospel of John, Vol. 2”). Ed. Migne, Jacques Paul. Vol. 14. Petit-Montrouge: Imprimerie Catholique, 1862. Trench, Richard Chenevix. [*Synonyms of the New Testament.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=yvgsAAAAYAAJ) 12th ed. London: Kegan, 1894. |

Comment: Your note on 'very bread' 'very light' 'very vine' is extremely interesting. +1. In the NT darkness is seen as a _kind_ of light. But it is not the essence of light. It is not, as you say 'very light'. It is a false light (akin to moonlight).

Comment: Excellent job of contrasting and explaining the two.

Comment: Your conclusions are a). Those who "abide in him"  bear much fruit,  and the same time the "vine" refers to "the nation of Israel," -seems there is inconsistency.  b). If "Very /true"  is used to denote - "very/true vine" because those who "abide in him" " bear much fruit" -  then, how can in v-2-every Branch IN ME not bear fruit"?

Comment: Could you please include in your answer as Q/A?

Answer (score 3):

Several things all coalesce in this first sentence in John 15, namely:

1. Jesus is "full of grace and truth" (John 1:18).  This is one of the matters that John wishes to establish and he does this by calling Jesus, eg, Jesus was the true light (John 1:9), the true glory (John 1:14), the true way of life (John 1:17), the true bread from heaven (John 6:32, 33, 55), true food (John 6:55), true witness (John 8:14, 16), the true and living way (John 14:6), etc.  Thus, Jesus emphasised that He was the real source of truth and thus the source of life of the true vine, Israel as the branches of that vine.
2. The sermon preached in John 15 & 16 was delivered by Jesus to the disciples while walking on the evening of His Gethsemane experience the night before the crucifixion.  It is entirely probable that they walked past a vineyard on their way from Jerusalem to the mount of olives.
3. The figure or metaphor of Israel being represented by a vine (ἄμπελος) occurs several times in the Old Testament, Ps 80:8, Isa 5:3-7, Jer 2:21, Eze 19:10, etc.  Therefore, Jesus took this opportunity to explain that He was the fulfilment of all the symbols and prophecies of the OT and this was yet another example of that.  Israel is the vine that grows from Jesus who is its true source of nourishment.  That is, there could be no Israel without Christ.

He also adds something extra in V5-8; He takes the opportunity to emphasise that we are completely dependant upon Jesus for all good things, especially life in our Chrsitian walk:

> I am the vine and you are the branches. The one who remains in Me, and
>   I in him, will bear much fruit. For apart from Me you can do nothing.
>   If anyone does not remain in Me, he is like a branch that is thrown
>   away and withers. Such branches are gathered up, thrown into the fire,
>   and burned. If you remain in Me and My words remain in you, ask
>   whatever you wish, and it will be done for you. This is to My Father’s
>   glory, that you bear much fruit, proving yourselves to be My
>   disciples.

In summary, while joined to Christ we can accomplish great things for Him and by Him; disconnected from Christ we will be cut off and thrown into the fire - we are lost.

Comment: My question was more on His use of the adj.  "true" describing  the "vine", was He contrasting? And,  you seem to agree -in  #3- with the view - "Vine" refers to "Israel" than Jesus Himself?

Comment: Answer updated to help

Comment: In your answer (1) "..  Israel as the branches of that vine" & (3)...Israel being represented by a vine (ἄμπελος)"-in effect, here, you are saying the "vine" represents the "Israel,"  and  at the same time your comment on v 5-8 says- "we ( christians?) are completely dependant upon "Jesus" for all good things". 
 If my understanding is correct, your answer indicates, in the context of one Parable,  vine=Israel & vine=Jesus,   seem it is inconsistent, especially, in consideration of words in V-5 -9,: "I am the vine"; abides in me...etc. Jesus is explicitly identifying Himself as the true vine.

Comment: @Sam - That is not what I said - Jesus used the well known figure of the vine to say that He was the true vine and we (as spiritual Israel) are the branches - completely dependant upon Him.

Comment: It's my bad, if I misunderstood the last part  of :"Thus, Jesus emphasised that He was the real source of truth and thus the source of life of the true vine, "Israel as the branches of that vine."

Answer (score 2):

John 6:32 "the true" bread from heaven, alethinon.

John 1:9 "the true" light, alethinon.

John 15:1 "the true" vine, alethine.

These are all to do with who Jesus is. As in "very God of very God"-verax- veracity-truly God. Other examples:

1 Thessalonians 1:9 "the living and true God" and
John 17:3 "the only true God".

A useful contradistinction being to compare "alethinon", who God is, with what is said:

John  3:33 "..his testimony..is true" different word here "alethes".

Romans 3:4 "let God be true..", "in your words".

Back to "alethinon, in Hebrews 8:2 "the true" tent is in heaven. The tabernacle in the wilderness was real but only a copy of the real/true thing.

Answer (score 2):

### Q: When Jesus said, I am “the true vine” (ἡ ἀληθινή )- in John 15:1, was the “true” a random choice, or is there any significance?

**Introduction**:

The parable in John 15:1-8, delivered by Jesus during an intimate moment with His disciples, encapsulates the culmination of His three-and-a-half years of discipleship ministry. This narrative serves as a transitional statement into the era of the disciples' mission. Within this parable, Jesus emphasizes the intimate relationship between the branches (disciples) and “the true vine” (Jesus), a concept intricately guided by the Holy Spirit (ref. John 16:1-15).

In this post, we will delve into the profound significance of Jesus's declaration, "I am the true vine" (John 15:1). Uttered on the way to Gethsemane after the Passover Supper, these carefully chosen words reveal a deeper layer of meaning. What secrets lie behind this declaration, and what insights can we gain from unraveling the layers of John 15:1-8?

**1.    The Message of John 15:1-8:**

Jesus paints a vivid picture of a vineyard, where God the Father is the vinedresser, and Jesus is the true vine. The disciples, represented as branches, are intricately connected to bear fruits pleasing to God. The essence lies in the mutual intimate relationship of abiding—'in Me and I in you' (Verse 5a). Without maintaining this connection, the expected 'fruit-bearing' is unattainable. Jesus emphasizes the importance of His words dwelling within the disciples, equating it with Him abiding in them.

However, a warning follows: branches that detach from the true vine will wither and be discarded. On a positive note, Jesus promises care for those abiding in Him, with answered requests, enabling them to be more fruitful to the delight of God, the Father.

**2.    The Significance of "I am the True Vine": A Spiritual Botanical Metaphor**

**a. “I AM the True Vine”**

“I AM” - Jesus unequivocally declares, "I am the true vine" in a statement of profound significance. This declaration, anchored in the powerful phrase "I am" ( Ἐγώ εἰμι ) emphasizes Jesus's eternal existence and self-identification, "I am."

“The True Vine” -The intentional use of adjectives, coupled with definite articles— “the vine, the true” (ἡ ἄμπελος ἡ ἀληθινή)—serves to accentuate authenticity, pure breeding, and genuineness.

This botanical metaphor sharply contrasts with all other vine trees, cross-pollinated vines, reinforcing Jesus's authenticity as the true Messiah. In doing so, He distinguishes Himself from those who preceded Him (John 10:8) and the self-proclaimed religious leaders of His time and in the days to come.

In essence, proclaiming Himself as the "True Vine," Jesus identifies and affirms, He is the promised 'Seed of Woman’ in Genesis 3:15-16, and long-prophesied “Yeshua Hamashiach” throughout the Old Testaments, and John the Baptist came to introduced Him the to Jewish community.  Additionally, Jesus reiterates and reaffirms His teachings, that in Him resides 'eternal life.' He is 'the way, the truth, and the pathway' to God, possessing the very 'words of eternal life.'

Thus, in likening Himself to 'the vine, the true,' Jesus solidifies His identity as the genuine Messiah for the world, a message the disciples are to proclaim to the entire world.

**b.  “You are the Branches.”**

The metaphor extends to the disciples as branches, symbolizing their chosen position in Jesus, Master-servants. As Jesus said, 'You did not choose Me, but I chose you,' as the Father gave you to Me (John 15:16; 17:24). It serves as a clear reminder that they are the ‘branches,’ not the ‘true vine tree.’ They are ‘servants,’ not the Master, - a culmination of Jesus’ Discipleship ministry. This underscores that the disciples' role, as faithful servants, is to propagate the gospel and teachings of Jesus. The metaphor emphasizes the disciples' distinct position and the paramount importance of their fidelity to the teachings they received.

Their purpose is to bear fruit, specifically the fruits aligned with the characteristics of the ‘true vine,’ not of their own. In this context, Jesus alludes to the disciples' responsibility to present Him, the true vine, as they have learned firsthand during their three-and-a-half years with Him. Jesus had instructed them, ‘Go therefore and make disciples of all nations...' – a preamble to their mission thereafter.

**c. Understanding the Nature of ‘Fruit’ the branches to bear.**

As pointed out above, this parable serves as a preamble to the disciples’ upcoming mission. In that regard, 'fruit-bearing' has more to do with producing disciples or converts, emphasizing the fulfillment of Christ's Great Commission outlined in Matthew 28:17-20. Jesus has prepared His disciples for their mission, to preach the salvation message (Ref. Mark 3:14; Luke 24:47) and to be the ‘witness - μάρτυς (martus) of Jesus’ to the utmost part of the world (Acts 1:8).

Furthermore, Jesus used progressive phraseologies, ‘bearing fruit,’ ‘more fruit,’ and ‘much fruit,’ a concept measurable and quantifiable, which emphasizes the abundance of ‘fruit’ in terms of numerical converts and disciples, not just an increase in the moral character of the disciples. This aligns with ‘You will do the greater than these because I am going to the Father’ (John 14:12).

In essence, the concept of 'fruit-bearing' in this parable underscores the disciples' mission to engage in global evangelism, aligning with the Great Commission, and emphasizes the abundance of conversions in fulfillment of Jesus' teachings.

Moreover, as Jesus declared, 'Already you are clean because of the word that I have spoken to you’ and ‘sanctified in truth’ (John 15:3; 17:18), this spiritual purification serves as the foundation for the disciples to carry forth the 'true-to-name,' unadulterated, message and teachings, representing Jesus, the genuine vine tree. Just as Jesus said,

"Go therefore and **make disciples of all nations,** baptizing them in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit, teaching them to observe all that **I** have commanded you" (Matthew 28:19-20), not to make their followers, or preach 'another gospel' (Galatians 1: 8- 9).

**3.    Implication of “I am the true vine, and you are the branches.”**

**a.    A Lesson to learn from Botanical Grafting.**

The science of propagating fruit trees teaches us that we can’t always grow a ‘true-to-name’ vine tree and fruit from planting vine seeds. This is because the seeds of each generation of vine tree carry the history of cross-pollinations from past generations. The fruit is merely a vessel for the seeds, and the seeds carry a history of traits from the parent tree and its pollination partners. The only dependable way to propagate the same original ‘true-to-name’ vine tree and fruit is by grafting branches onto the true vine tree.

The implication of this botanical lesson is that disciples themselves are akin to the ‘fruit’ with the ‘good seed’ of the ‘true vine tree,’ the carriers of the good seeds, emphasizing the importance of remaining grafted onto the true vine, Jesus.

**b.    Jesus is the first source of ‘true-to-name’ vine tree and fruits to be propagated.**

Jesus serves as the source of the 'true-to-name' vine tree and the fruits meant for propagation. In Verse 5a, the parable emphasizes a central point: Jesus is the true vine, and those who abide in Him will bring forth much fruit, fruit that is 'true-to-name.'

Verses 4, 5b, and 6 elaborate on the consequences of not abiding in Jesus. Failure to do so results in the inability to bear 'true-to-name' fruit, leading to eventual removal and burning. Verses 3, 4a, and 7 show clearly that abiding 'In me and I in you' with both the 'words of Jesus' and Jesus Himself abiding, cleansing believers, and enabling them to bring forth 'true-to-name' fruits. Jesus, in the Gospel books, spoke on several occasions, His word as ‘good seed’ figuratively.

Finally, in Verses 1-2 and 8, the focus shifts to God and the different types of branches. Jesus declares that God will remove or purge branches not abiding in Jesus and His word. Eschatologically, branches destined for fire result from bearing 'bad fruits' or engaging in the 'working of lawlessness,' acting autonomously as if they are 'god,' knowing good and evil, mirroring the disobedience and self-will seen in the biblical narrative of the fall.

In contrast, branches faithfully abiding in Jesus and His word will bring forth much fruit, ultimately glorifying the Father, the Husbandman."

**In summary:**

Jesus urges His disciples to diligently guard and pass on the 'true vine tree' that He represents Jesus, along with His teachings. This responsibility entails preserving and propagating the true Jesus and His words, the “good seed” (Matthew 13:24) without adding or subtracting, adulteration, abuse, or distortion—a crucial trust placed in the hands of the disciples.

**Conclusion:**

This parable, delivered in a private setting to the eleven disciples, serves as timeless instruction for successive disciples, servants, and sowers tasked with carrying the Gospel torch to all nations. This encompasses preachers, teachers, missionaries, and writers.

Disciples, both then and now, are urged to steadfastly abide in Jesus and His words, eschewing the insincere peddling of God’s words. The teachings should remain untainted by ‘traditions’ and ‘doctrines of men.’

The specific declaration, ‘I am the true vine,’ encapsulates the essence of Jesus (and His words) as an authentic ‘true-to-name’ vine tree and ‘good seed.’ Disciples and sowers are tasked with propagating and multiplying without succumbing to ‘cross-pollination’ from worldly teachings and those of man. Their responsibility involves preserving and propagating the message without adulteration, abuse, or distortion motivated by personal gain or interests. This is a trust of utmost importance.

Jesus assures special care for those abiding in Him, promising answered requests and enabling them to be more fruitful to the delight of God, the Father. Conversely, those detaching from the true vine, standing, and acting alone as the wicked and lawless ones, bear no fruit that the Husbandman, God the Father, seeks. They will wither and be thrown into the fire to be burned.

In closing, the apostles, pioneers of the Great Commission, exemplified unwavering loyalty by faithfully passing on the ‘true vine tree’ and the ‘good seed’ to subsequent generations with their lives. Their commitment ensures the continuity of the gospel message, echoing the call for all disciples to abide in the true vine and bear enduring fruit. This fruit is ‘true-to-name’ of Jesus Christ, our Lord and Savior.

**Soli Deo Glora!  Sola Scriptura!  Sola Fide!  Solus Christus! Sola Gratia!**